# Callback problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I am new into javascript, and currently I'm trying to learning callback to my script. This script should return reduced words in array of objects

```js
var fs = require('fs')
var dict = ['corpus.txt','corpus1.txt','corpus2.txt'];

mapping(dict, function(error,data){
 if(error) throw error
 console.log(data)
})

function mapping(list, callback){
 var txtObj = []
 list.forEach(function (val) {
  readFile(val, function(error,data){
   txtObj.push(data)
  })
 })
 function readFile(src, cb){
  fs.readFile(src,'utf8', function (error,data) {
   if (error) return callback(error,null)
   return mapred(data)
  })
 }
 return callback(null,txtObj)
}
```

But it returns empty array. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to invoke `callback` not immediately, but later, when all `readFile` are done. This is a bit tricky, as you have multiple files. Try to get it working with a single file first. Once you understand how that works, come back with another question on how to make it work with many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
`fs.readFile`
```

is an asynchronous function, before it's done and result callback is invoked, you are returning the empty `txtObj` array.

how to fix it ?

call `return callback(null,txtObj)`  after     `fs.readFile`  is finished running.

and also, as you are running asynchronous function on an array of items one-by-one,  it might not still work the way you want. might want to use `modudles` like `async` in nodejs

Here comes an **asynchronous** version using module async. **synchronous file operation is strongly objected** :)

```
var fs = require('fs')
var dict = ['corpus.txt','corpus1.txt','corpus2.txt'];

mapping(dict, function(error,data){
    if(error) throw error
    console.log(data)
})

function mapping(list, callback){
    var txtObj = [],
        async = require('async');

    async.each(list, readFile, function(err) {
        callback(err,txtObj)
    });

    function readFile(src, cb) {
        fs.readFile(src,'utf8', function (error,data) {
            if (error) {
                cb(error);
            }
            else {
                txtObj.push(mapred(data));
                cb(null);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

**EDIT : You can do this without async, but it is little bit dirty isn't it ?**  also its OK if you remove the self invoking function inside the forEach, i included so that you can access the val, even after the callback is done

```
var fs = require('fs')
var dict = ['corpus.txt','corpus1.txt','corpus2.txt'];

mapping(dict, function(error,data){
    if(error) throw error
    console.log(data)
})

function mapping(list, callback){
    var txtObj = [],
        counter = list.length,
        start = 0;

    list.forEach(function (val) {
        (function(val)
            readFile(val, function(error,data) {
                txtObj.push(data);
                start++;
                if(error || (start === counter)) {
                    callback(error,txtObj);
                }

        }))(val);
    })

    function readFile(src, cb) {
        fs.readFile(src,'utf8', function (error,data) {
            if (error) {
                cb(error);
            }
            else {
                txtObj.push(mapred(data));
                cb(null);
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I know a little bit about using async, but I'm looking for more "elegant" way  using callback. Isn't there any solution without async?

Comment: @pacific01 : i edited my answer with out async module,  but with async - its far simpler and readable

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting an empty array result is that you are performing the callback before the readFile function has a chance to populate the array. You are performing multiple asynchronous actions but not letting them to complete before continuing.

If there was only one async action, you would call `callback()` in the callback function of readFile, but as you need to perform multiple async actions before calling `callback()`, you should consider using `fs.readFileSync()`.

Sometimes sync cannot be avoided.

```
function mapping(list, callback)
{
    var txtObj = []
    list.forEach(function(val)
    {
        try { txtObj.push(mapred(fs.readFileSync(val, 'utf8'))) }
        catch(err) { callback(err) }
    })
    callback(null, txtObj)
}
```

Comment: Hmm... Depending on the use-case, `readFileSync` may be perfectly fine, but it certainly *could* be avoided here. You just need some tool to manage a "list of Futures" (which I agree may be a bit daunting for a beginner).